# Prevent AJAX passing null value to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an AJAX method that is sent to a controller. The problem is that when, for some reason, I have to delete all values from the input with the ID CP, it throws an error because it says I am sending a null value to my controller. To prevent this situation, I added an if statement but it doesn't seem to work. Can you give me a code that avoids sending values to the controller if my variable is empty?

```
$("#CP").on("change", function () {
    console.log("esta corriendo el onchange")

    var url = '/Propiedades/ListarColonias';

    var CP = $('#CP').val();
    if (CP == null) {
        CP = 10640;
    }

    $("#c.p").val(CP)
    console.log(CP)
    if (CP !== null) {
        var data = { CodigoPostal: CP }

        $.post(url, data).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);

            var $select = $('<select>');
            $select.append($('<option>').val('').text('Seleccione una colonia')); // Agrega una opción en blanco
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                $select.append($('<option>').val(item.idColonia).text(item.colonia));
            });

            $('#Colonia').html($select.html()); // Actualiza el contenido del dropdownlist existente

            return data
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this, then the CP is never null, then the server has issues

```js
const url = '/Propiedades/ListarColonias';
$("#CP").on("change", function() {
  console.log("esta corriendo el onchange")
  let CP = $(this).val() || 10640; // cannot be null now
  $("#c.p").val(CP); // what is this field?
  console.log(CP)
  let postalCodeData = { CodigoPostal: CP }
  $.post(url, postalCodeData).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $('#Colonia').html(`<select><option value="">Seleccione una colonia</option>
      ${{data.map(item => `<option value="${item.idColonia}">${item.colonia}</option>`).join("")}`);
  });
});
```